# Can't get selected value from dropdown

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-form

I have a form that contains an input and a dropdown that's filled with elements from an API. But I'm having a probem, whenever I submit the form It only passes the value from the input and not the dropdown.

It's weird because when I click inspect element on the form it show that each option has a value and a label.

My code is simple, I have a form that has an input and a dropdown, I get an int from the input and a value from the dropdown and it creates an element via POST request, but that happens in the background since I only pass the parameters here.

I am using the [Redux Form](https://redux-form.com/8.2.2/) library for my form controls

here's my code:

```
import React from 'react';
import {reduxForm, Field} from 'redux-form';
import {Input} from 'reactstrap';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import { renderField } from '../form';
import {ticketAdd} from "../actions/actions";
import {Message} from "./Message";

const mapDispatchToProps = {
    ticketAdd
};

class AmendeForm extends React.Component {

    onSubmit(values) {
        const { ticketAdd, parkingId } = this.props;
        return ticketAdd(parseInt(values.matricule),parkingId,parseInt(values.montant));
    }

    render() {
        const { handleSubmit, submitting, voitureList } = this.props;
        console.log(voitureList);

        if (null === voitureList) {
            return (<Message message="Pas de voitures"/>); 
        }

        return (
            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(this.onSubmit.bind(this))}>
                <Input type="select" name="matricule" id="exampleSelect" label="Matricule">
                {
                    voitureList.map(voiture => {
                        return ( 
                            <option value={voiture.id} key={voiture.id}>{voiture.matricule}</option>
                        );
                    })
                }  
                </Input>

                <Field name="montant" type="number" label="Montant" component={renderField}/>

                <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary btn-big btn-block" disabled={submitting}>Ajouter ticket</button>
            </form>
        )
    }
}

export default reduxForm({
    form: 'AmendeForm'
})(connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(AmendeForm))
```

Comment: Which library are you using to build your forms? What is `handleSubmit` in your code? It seems to be the responsible to get the values of the form.

Comment: I'm using redux-form, I'm not sure about ```HandleSubmit``` since I'm following a tutorial, it binds all the data in the form after onSubmit so I can access it later

Comment: Your dropdown is not making use of any redux-form `Field`, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because your dropdown form field isn't wrapped by `redux-form` `<Field />` component.

You have to create a custom dropdown Component (let's name it `<Dropdown />`) and later pass it to the Field as follows:

```
<Field name='matricule' component={Dropdown} />
```

Keep in mind that in your `<Dropdown />` component, you have to adapt the props passed down by `<Field />` with your custom Dropdown props. For example, `<Field />` will pass down `input` prop, which includes itself `onChange`, `onBlur` and other handlers, these should be passed down to your custom Dropdown too.

Here's a basic example how to create such a custom Dropdown component:

```
const Dropdown = ({ input, label, options }) => (
  <div>
    <label htmlFor={label}>{label}</label>
    <select {...input}>
      <option>Select</option>
      { options.map( o => (
          <option key={o.id} value={o.id}>{o.label}</option> 
        )
      )}
    </select>
  </div>
)
```

**Usage**

```
const options = [
  { id: 1, label: 'Example label 1' },
  { id: 2, label: 'Example label 2' }
]

<Field name='marticule' component={Dropdown} options={options} />
```

---

For advanced use-cases, [please refer to the docs](https://redux-form.com/6.6.3/docs/api/field.md/#usage).

Also, you're using `reactstrap`, and [here's a discussion](https://github.com/reactstrap/reactstrap/issues/707) of how to create such custom Dropdown component, which is adapted with `redux-form`.